# does the spritebatch draws multiple stages with a single batch? Libgdx

Tags: libgdx

The title says it all.

does calling multiple `Stage`s draw() method with the same `SpriteBatcher` object happens only in a single batch or it is one `Stage` = one batch?

I have a situation where i dont want to use actors for the background of the game, i just draw it directly. But the algo looks like this.

> 1. begin batch
> 2. draw background
> 3. end batch
> 4. call all stage draw

If your answer is: the spritebatch will draw multiple stages in one batch, then I can say that it is more efficient to put each sprites as a member to an Actor object and then add all Actor object to the Stage object, then call the stage draw. This way, i can minimize the call to begin batch and end batch which can improve performance as what i know.

Comment: Modern low end phones can do roughly 50 draw calls before frame rate drops below 60 FPS. Of course, there are other factors that can affect that, but it's almost certainly not worth complicating your code to save one draw call.

Comment: an additional information. great. thanks.

Comment: One other thing. Buttons and Tables in libgdx also cause a batch flush by default, so you will get an extra draw call on each of them unless you call setTransform(false); on them, which is fine as long as you don't plan to scale or rotate them. Those really can add up if you use a lot of buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [`Stage`s code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.java), it seems like it calls `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()`:

```
public void draw () {
    Camera camera = viewport.getCamera();
    camera.update();

    if (!root.isVisible()) return;

    Batch batch = this.batch;
    if (batch != null) {
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        root.draw(batch, 1);
        batch.end();
    }

    if (debug) drawDebug();
}
```

So adding your `Actor`s to the `Stage` might reduce the draw calls.
But remember, that if the `Batch` is full, it will be `flush()`ed anyways, which results in a draw call.
So it does not necessarily decrease the number of draw calls. Also don't think about performance to much, as long as you don't have perforrmance problems. If the other solutions seams "cleaner", i guess it is not worth changing it.
One important thing to remeber, when working with more then one `Batch` is, to call `end()` for one, before calling `begin()` for the other. You should never have 2 `Batch`es "running" at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. I dont know that batch can be full.

Comment: Using the default constructor, the `SpriteBatch` can contain 1000 `Sprite`s, before calling `flush()`. You can increase that size by using the constructor with the `int size`, maximum here is 5460. You can read this [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#SpriteBatch-int-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram-)

Comment: iThank you for your answer. I don't understand why `root` and `viewport` members of `Stage` class are `private` instead of `protected`. We could overwrite the `draw` method by extending `Stage` class.

Comment: I tested it, imported whole scene2d into my project and removed the `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()` in the `draw` method of `Stage` class so that i only have one `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()`. Framerate didn't change even 1FPS. So don't worry about it.

Comment: @EnesBattal i guess, that a few drawcallse more or less won't affect performance that much. But just a question: Did you test that on a phone or on desktop? I guess on a low-end android phone you will notice the performance loss much earlier, then on a desktop with more hardware ressources.

Comment: I tested on a relatively old phone (HTC Desire S with ICS)

Comment: @EnesBattal cool, so we know, that a few draw calls more or less won't affect the performance to much.